# Blocking deployments initiated via sfdx/ant

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata-api

I have removed `Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions` [permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=meta_modify_metadata_perm.htm&type=5) for my user with hopes that removing this permission I can avoid any deployment using sfdx/ant. This didn't help. I can still execute a custom object deploy using sfdx....

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have given "Modify All Data" permissions .

Modify all data permission gives ability to create and deploy metadata. Check the official docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321298&language=en_US&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&mode=1)